# How to run "tf get" without ui prompting for credentials

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tf-cli

I have a bat file that runs "tf get" automatically once each day. I'm logging in using /login with a PAT. That works. However, after a couple of days (7?), i receive the message "You are not authorized to access [severname].visualstudio.com.

In that case, i need to call "tf get" (without any parameters) which will then display a login ui where i have to enter my actual username and password. After having logged in, my script runs successfully for a couple of day after which i end up with the "no authorized" message again.

I would like to be able to run a "tf get" without any ui prompting for credentials. How can i do this?

Comment: Hi there, may I know if your organization is connected to any AAD? If yes, I am thinking if we can authenticate against the service principal instead of user principal in your AAD that is also add to your DevOps organization. And we can generate AAD token for the service pricipal  each time before `tf get` as the credential instead of PAT.

Comment: We are not actively using an aad, however, isn't everyone who is using AzureDevOps part of an AAD? I do not understand the rest of your comment. Hod wo i "add the service principal to the DevOps org"? How to i create an "AAD token for the service principal"?

Comment: I believe your Azure DevOps organization is connected to your AAD. I will share the method in the answer. Hope the information could help.

Comment: Thank you. I just looked at the Organization Settings --> Azure Active Directory and there is no Directory given. Instead, there is a button labeled "Connect directory". So it appears, this Org is not connected to an AAD. Also, when i try to "Add new users", there are no Service Principals listed.

Answer (score 0):

If one Azure DevOps organization is connected an AAD, the users in this organization should have the mapping `User Principals` in AAD. In addition, we cannot only add `User Principals` of the connected AAD into our DevOps organization, but also add `Service Principals`.

[image]

Similar to the `User Principals` in a DevOps organization, `Service Principals` should receive user licenses (Basic) and sufficient permissions to access the TFVC repo.

Here is the sample [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) command running in CMD that we can use to **authenticate** against a `Service Principal` in my DevOps organization, generate the **AAD token** to access **Azure DevOps resource** for this Service Principal and use this Oauth token as the credential for `tf get` command. I succeeded to get the TFVC repo updates from server with this methods.

```
set TenantId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
set ApplicationId=yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
set ClientSecret=sn~*********D-_************CXa8r
az login --service-principal --username %ApplicationId% --password %ClientSecret% --tenant %TenantId%

set azureDevopsResourceId=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
for /f %i in ('az account get-access-token --resource %azureDevopsResourceId% --query "accessToken" --output tsv') do set token=%i
echo token is %token%

tf get /loginType:OAuth /login:.,%token%
```

[image]
[image]
Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#3-access-azure-devops-resources-with-a-microsoft-entra-token) for more details.